# horizontal menu stays on when sub menu is selected function

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the main parent menu item is hovered, it will remain active while traversing the sub-menu of that item, even when over a child element. But this does not occur, why?

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kh2vm/)

**JS**

```
var mastertabvar = new Object()
mastertabvar.baseopacity = 0
mastertabvar.browserdetect = ""

function showsubmenu(masterid, id) {
    submenuobject = document.getElementById(id)
    mastertabvar.browserdetect = submenuobject.filters ? "ie" : typeof submenuobject.style.MozOpacity == "string" ? "mozilla" : ""
    hidesubmenus(mastertabvar[masterid])
    submenuobject.style.display = "block"
    instantset(mastertabvar.baseopacity)
    highlighting = setInterval("gradualfade(submenuobject)", 0)
}

function hidesubmenus(submenuarray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < submenuarray.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(submenuarray[i]).style.display = "none"
}

function instantset(degree) {
    if (mastertabvar.browserdetect == "mozilla") submenuobject.style.MozOpacity = degree / 100
    else if (mastertabvar.browserdetect == "ie") submenuobject.filters.alpha.opacity = degree
}

function gradualfade(cur2) {
    if (mastertabvar.browserdetect == "mozilla" && cur2.style.MozOpacity < 1) cur2.style.MozOpacity = Math.min(parseFloat(cur2.style.MozOpacity) + 0.1, 0.99)
    else if (mastertabvar.browserdetect == "ie" && cur2.filters.alpha.opacity < 100) cur2.filters.alpha.opacity += 10
    else if (typeof highlighting != "undefined") //fading animation over
    clearInterval(highlighting)
}

function initalizetab(tabid) {
    mastertabvar[tabid] = new Array()
    var menuitems = document.getElementById(tabid).getElementsByTagName("li")
    for (var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++) {
        if (menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel")) {
            menuitems[i].setAttribute("rev", tabid) //associate this submenu with main tab
            mastertabvar[tabid][mastertabvar[tabid].length] = menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel") //store ids of submenus of tab menu
            if (menuitems[i].className == "selected") showsubmenu(tabid, menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel")) menuitems[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onmouseover = function() {
                showsubmenu(this.parentNode.getAttribute("rev"), this.parentNode.getAttribute("rel"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.basictab{
    margin-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: gray;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.basictab li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/mainbar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: rgba(0,51,0,1);
    background-position: left;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0px 0px;
}

.basictab li a{
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: gray;
    border-right-color: gray;
    border-bottom-color: gray;
    border-left-color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(../images/mainbar.png);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}


.basictab li a:visited{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.basictab li a:hover{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-image: url(../images/behindbar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.basictab li a:active{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-image: url(../images/behindbar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.basictab li.selected a{ /*selected tab effect*/
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #dbffff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-image: url(../images/behindbar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}


.submenustyle{
    border-top-width: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: none;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/behindbar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    font-size: 12px;
    background-position: left;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    word-spacing: 4em;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

* html .submenustyle{ /*IE only width definition*/
width: 100%;
}

.submenustyle a{

    padding: 1px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.submenustyle a:hover{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgba(255,153,0,1);
}#navMenu {
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <ul id="maintab" class="basictab">
        <li class="active" rel="cyst"><a href="cyphm.htm">1</a></li>
        <li rel="cylim"><a href="cylim.htm">2</a></li>
        <li rel="cynic"><a href="cynic.htm">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="cypfo.htm">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="cyplca.htm">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="cyfam.htm">6</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="cyst" class="submenustyle">
        <a href="cyfd.htm">1</a>
        <a href="cycl.htm">2</a>
        <a href="cybr.htm">3</a>
        <a href="cylm.htm">4</a>
        <a href="cyth.htm">5</a>
        <a href="cycin.htm">6</a>
    </div>

    <div id="cynic" class="submenustyle">
        <a href="nicfd.htm">1</a>
        <a href="niccl.htm">2</a>
        <a href="nicbr.htm">3</a>
        <a href="niclm.htm">4</a>
        <a href="nicth.htm">5</a>
        <a href="niccin.htm">6</a>
    </div>

    <div id="cylim" class="submenustyle">
        <a href="limfd.htm">1</a>
        <a href="limcl.htm">2</a>
        <a href="limbr.htm">3</a>
        <a href="limlm.htm">4</a>
        <a href="limth.htm">5</a>
        <a href="limcin.htm">6</a>
    </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
//initialize tab menu, by passing in ID of UL
initalizetab("maintab")
</script>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Woah, why not use jQuery instead of that mess of javascript?

Comment: That mess of JavaScript is from an [**online tutorial**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/2leveltab.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

This is the "classic" way, but works very well.

**HTML:**

```html
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        parent
        <ul>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        parent
        <ul>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
  ul#navigation > li > ul { display: none; }
  ul#navigation > li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but if you want the background of the parent item to stay highlighted while hovering the submenu items, then you can do it with this:

```
ul li {
    background: #CCC;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #0CF;
}​
```

Parent and child li's will both use that.
http://jsfiddle.net/zEkXu/

---

But you could also do this with jQuery:

```
$(".submenustyle").hover(function() {
    $(".basictab").css({"background-color":"#0CF"});
}, function() {
    $(".basictab").css({"background-color":"#CCC"});
});
```

Which means: do something (in this case change background color) when hovering the submenus.

Comment: I revised the description of the problem so it's easier to understand. Cheers!